# Add a parameter to a function pointer

Tags: c, parameter-passing, function-pointers

I'm using a function pointer to delegate states in C.

```
// states
void state1(int first, int second) {
    ...
}

void state2(int first, int second) {
    ...
}

// state pointer
void (*current_state)(int, int);

// state logic
if (condition1) {
    current_state = &state_1;
} else if (condition2) {
    current_state = &state_2;
}

// do the thing
(*current_state)(1, 2);
```

Now I'm at a point where the given arguments no longer suffice, so there is a third argument needed. Since I don't want to change all states, I wondered if it is possible to pass a quasi constant parameter along with the pointer. Something like this:

```
void state3(int first, int second, int third) {
    ...
}

// state logic
...
else if (condition3) {
    // calculate the constant third argument
    int param3 = 0;

    current_state = &state_3(int, int, param3);
}
```

I there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do (dynamically declare the function prototype?), but why don't simply use a **variadic** function?

Comment: FIY: `current_state = &state_1;` can be written with one less token as `current_state = state_1;`

Comment: I suggest combining all the parameters into a struct, then passing a pointer to the struct. While this requires changing the function prototypes once, it will not have to be done again. It also avoids the ugliness of varargs. To avoid having to change the existing state functions much, lines like `int first = args->first;` could be added to the top of each functions.

Comment: Another solution is to pass a single `va_list`. The function prototype remain the same the arguments in the list can be whatever you want and how many you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure I'd recommend it but you could do this sort of thing:

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
typedef int pfun();
int alice( int a, int b)        { return b; }
int bob( int a, int b, int c)   { return c;     }

int main( )
{
pfun*   f;
    f = alice;
    printf( "%d\n", f( 1, 2, 3));
    f = bob;
    printf( "%d\n", f( 1, 2, 3));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This compiles with

```
gcc -o funp -Wall  funp.c
```

without warnings and runs correctly.

The point is that a function declaration like

```
int f();
```

Says that f is a function that returns an int, with unspecified arguments. The downside is that the compiler cannot check that the arguments are of the correct type.

Comment: Calling alice with invalid number of arguments results in undefined behaviour. You should never use prototypeless functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `*void` pointer and cast it to the concrete type in the state function. All state functions will have the same signature. Something like this:

```
// states
struct state1_args {
    int first;
    int second;
};

struct state2_args {
    float first;
    float second;
    float third;
};

void state1(void* state_args) {
    struct state1_args* args = (struct state1_args*)state_args;
    use(args->first);
    ...
}

void state2(void* state_args) {
    struct state2_args* args = (struct state2_args*)state_args;
    use(args->third);
    ...
}

// state pointer
void (*current_state)(void*);

// state logic
if (condition1) {
    current_state = &state_1;
    current_state_args = &args_1;
} else if (condition2) {
    current_state = &state_2;
    current_state_args = &args_2;
}

// do the thing
(*current_state)(current_state_args);
```